# Open set problem

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to learn topology today and I've met some problems. Can anyone help me here?
Defined in $\mathbb{R}^1$
Why isn't $G_{\delta}$ set $\{0\}=\bigcap^{\infty}_{n=1}(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$ an open set?

Comment: Because for any $\epsilon > 0$  : $B_{\epsilon}(0) \cap \mathbb{R}$ / $G_{\delta} \ne 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subset $O$ of $\mathbb R$ is open if (and only if) for each $x\in O$ there is a $\varepsilon>0$ such that $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\subset O$. But $0$ is the only element of $\{0\}$ and, if you take $\varepsilon>0$, $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\not\subset\{0\}$.